# How to read in pixel values from .pgm file and copy it into an array. c-programming

Tags: c, pgm

I've been stuck on this for a while. How would I go about copying pixel values 0-255 from a pgm file into an array? This is what I have so far. I know I'm off from what it is suppose to be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, int *argv[])
{


      int i = 0, j = 0;
      unsigned int str[1000];
      FILE *pgmFile;

      if (argc != 2)
      {
          printf ("ERROR, Not enough arguments.");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      if ((pgmFile = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
      {
          printf ("ERROR, File cannot be opened");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      do 
      {
          fscanf (pgmFile, "%d", str[i]);
          printf ("%d", str[i]);
          i++;
      }
      while (str[i] != EOF);



     fclose (pgmFile);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: So this reads the file line-by-line and prints them out? Then all you need to do is read the header lines (ignoring comment lines) then split up white-space separated lines with the pixel values I think? Which part are you stuck with?

Comment: I'll work on the header next then, but when I run this code on my pgm file I get 0 for white spaces and numbers like 1882140160 for black spaces. Why does it break out of the 0-255 range? my picture is black and white.

Comment: Your loop termination is off. First, fscanf returns EOF. Second, you increment `i` before the while condition is checked, so you're reading into unitialized memory. This probably means you're "reading" past the end of the file at which point you'll print out garbage in `str`.

Answer (score 0):

You should first read in the header (3 lines).

Using the data from the header, you can setup a for loop reading in the Y amount of lines. Within each line you should read X amount of pixel data and a new-line. If any of read functions returns an error-code, you should print out an error message and abort.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format